# Testlink 1.9.5 JIRA integration

Tags: jira, testlink

I am trying to integrate testlink 1.9.5 with JIRA from the issue tracker management view in testlink.

This is what I have written:

```
<!-- Template jirasoapInterface -->
<issuetracker>
<username>user</username>
<password>password</password>
<uribase>http://url.address</uribase>
<uriwsdl>http://url.address/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl</uriwsdl>
<uriview>http://url.address/browse/</uriview>
<uricreate>http://url.address/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa</uricreate>
<projectkey>projectkey</projectkey>
</issuetracker>
```

The problem is that I receive *"Connection is KO, check configuration"* while testing the connection and following text in the test execution view:

> "Attention Please: 
>   Something is preventing connection to Bug Tracking System,
>   and is going to create performance issues.
>   Please contact your TestLink Administrator"

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Well i managed to resolve this issue by changing the address to http://127.0.0.1/ althought I encountered a new problem. I have to figure out how to manage mandatory fields in testlink since the bug integration crashes during launch.

Answer (score 1):

After being all day searching for a solution to the same problem (in my case Testlink v1.9.13 + Atlassian Jira v6.5), i've discovered that if you put the email account (the same as i used to do login at Atlassian) on bug tracker configuration like this: `<username>name.surname@example.com</username>`,
it won't work, it's necessary to put the username associated to the email account.
This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

it's a example of my options in testlink

```
<!-- Template jirasoapInterface -->
<issuetracker>
<username>yourusernameAdmininJIRA</username>
<password>yourpasswordAdmininJIRA</password>
<uribase>https://yourJIRAhttps</uribase>
<uriwsdl>https://yourJIRAhttps</uriwsdl>
<uriview>https://yourJIRAhttps</uriview>
<uricreate>https://yourJIRAhttps</uricreate>
<issuetype>1</issuetype>
<projectkey>TOL</projectkey>
</issuetracker>
```

But username - you must enter your username admin in JIRA, password - also your admin JIRA. 
In field - uribase uriwsdl, uriview uricreate - you must write your server JIRA information.

Projectkey - it's a first sybols in your project in JIRA

Answer (score 0):

```
<issuetracker>
<username></username>
<password></password>
<uribase>https://jira.xxx.net/browse/"Project Prefix"</uribase>


<uriapi>https://jira.xxx.net/rest/api/latest/</uriapi>
<uriview>https://jira.xxx.net/browse/</uriview>
<userinteraction>1</userinteraction>
<!-- 1: User will be able to manage following attributes from GUI -->  
<!-- Issue Type, Issue Priority, Affects Versions, Components -->
<!-- 0: values for attributes will be taken FROM this config XML from  GUI -->

<!-- Configure This if you want be able TO CREATE ISSUES -->
<projectkey>"Project Prefix"</projectkey>
<issuetype>1</issuetype>
</issuetracker>
```